# Ethereum Blockchain - whitelist ip for smart contracts

Tags: ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

I'm looking to build a ethereum private blockchain, and will like to only restrict a particular user or ip address that can upload smart contracts to our chain.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible

Comment: We are always glad to help but you need to make an attempt yourself first. If after [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) you can't solve it, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read the [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937).